# Intergrating Nagios + Ganglia: UNKNOWN Hostname info not available. Likely invalid hostname

Tags: nagios, ganglia

I'm trying to integrate Nagios and Ganglia using methods described [here](https://github.com/ganglia/monitor-core/wiki/Integrating-Ganglia-with-Nagios). While using the [Ganglia Web Nagios script](https://github.com/ganglia/ganglia-web/wiki/Nagios-Integration), check_heartbeat, in command line:

`sh /var/www/html/ganglia/nagios/check_heartbeat.sh host=node-name threshold=50`

Output:
`OK Last beacon received 0 days, 0:00:00`

But in the Nagios UI, I'm getting the message as,

`UNKNOWN x.x.x.x - Hostname info not available. Likely invalid hostname`

I found some discussions based on the same issues in the following links

- https://github.com/ganglia/monitor-core/issues/40
- http://sourceforge.net/p/ganglia/mailman/ganglia-general/thread/alpine.DEB.2.00.1205211147590.6484@localhost6.localdomain6/

As I'm new to Ganglia and Nagios, they didn't give me the idea to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
define command {
    command_name  check_ganglia_heartbeat
    command_line  /bin/sh /var/www/html/ganglia/nagios/check_heartbeat.sh host=$HOSTADDRESS$ threshold=$ARG1$
}
```

to

```
define command {
    command_name  check_ganglia_heartbeat
    command_line  /bin/sh /var/www/html/ganglia/nagios/check_heartbeat.sh host=$HOSTNAME$ threshold=$ARG1$
}
```

I was able to solve this error.